# How to configure Azure AD to enable refresh tokens

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I have an Azure App Service / Web API linked to Azure AD and authentication is working, however client tokens are expiring after 1 hour, so I want to enable the OAuth refresh_token.  When I inspect the results of calling /.auth/me on my service I don't see a refresh_token.  Token store is enabled on the app service.

I have tried to add it to the `oauth2permissions` in the Azure AD manifest as follows, but it doesn't appear (I have restarted the App service and redeployed my service in case of caching of tokens) :

```
"oauth2Permissions": [ 
    {
        "adminConsentDescription": "Allow the application to store a refresh token on behalf of the signed-in user.",
        "adminConsentDisplayName": "Refresh tokens",
        "id": "3AGH4D29-B64A-4A9A-8DBC-5DB3C8BBBD75",
        "isEnabled": true,
        "type": "User",
        "userConsentDescription": "Allow the application to store a refresh token on your behalf.",
        "userConsentDisplayName": "Store refresh token",
        "value": "refresh_token"
    }
]
```

I have based my attempts on the guidance given here :
https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/07/app-service-token-store/

Comment: Are you using some library (ADAL.Net for example)? Please see this blog post from Vittorio: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2015/08/13/adal-3-didnt-return-refresh-tokens-for-5-months-and-nobody-noticed/.

Comment: @GauravMantri that's interesting, thanks, it has given me something to think about.  It may be that the client isn't requesting the token.  I am using the Azure mobile service client sdk to authenticate.  At the moment I am using the MobileServiceClient.LoginAsync() method, which is perhaps an abstraction over ADAL, I'll have to look into it.  I have seen lots of samples of authenticating more 'manually', which may give me the control to request the refresh_token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this using the guidance here : https://cgillum.tech/2016/03/25/app-service-auth-aad-graph-api/

Basically you have to update the auth settings of your app service.  And there isn't a UI for it, so I used the azure resource explorer.

The key was setting the additionalLoginParams value to `["response_type=code id_token", "resource=https://graph.windows.net"]`.