# How to use RenewToken method of MSADAL in Angular 6+?

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, adal

I am using MS Adal NPM package (https://www.npmjs.com/package/microsoft-adal-angular6) for Angular 6 to get the user Authenticated with Azure AD.  I am using Implicit Flow to get the Access token. I have been able to get Access token succesfully, with the following code in the constructor.

```
if (!this.adalSvc.userInfo) {
   this.adalSvc.login();
 } else {
   const token = this.adalSvc.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com').subscribe((token: string) => {
     localStorage.setItem('authtoken', token);
   });
 }
```

In the Implicit Flow, only Access Token is returned and this access token has an expiry period of one hour. I need to refresh this token. The documentation page of microsoft-adal-angular6 package mentions about the method **RenewToken**. However, I cannot see any details of this method and I could also not get any sample code that can show me how to use this method. Could anyone help me with this ?

Comment: You should be able to call acquireToken every time when you need a token and it'll get a new token when needed or return the cached token when it is still valid.

Comment: I called the acquireToken again, but I am getting the same token (probably from cache) with the same expiry time. For e.g. If I got the access token at 10:00 AM then the start time of the expiry time will be 10:00 AM. If I get a new token at 10:30 then the start time of the expiry time should be 10:30 A.M.  How do I get a new token with new expiry time if I use acquireToken again and again.?

Comment: With ADAL I don't think it was possible.. You could (as a hack) delete the token from local/session storage and ADAL would be forced to refresh it. In typical scenarios this is unnecessary though. You would normally just call acquireToken every time, and if it fails, require interactive login at that time. It'll refresh the token automatically 5-10 minutes before expiry AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a nice explanation in the website https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/authentication/auth-silent-aad about how ADAL creates a hidden IFrame.

> **The ADAL.js library creates a hidden iframe** for OAuth 2.0 implicit
>   grant flow, but it specifies prompt=none so that Azure AD never shows
>   the login page. If user interaction is required because the user needs
>   to log in or grant access to the application, Azure AD will
>   immediately return an error that ADAL.js then reports to your app. At
>   this point your app can show a login button if needed.

The solution was very simple. I had to just write one line of code

```
this.adalsvc.RenewToken('https://graph.microsoft.com');
```

The only point to note here is that, since "adalsvc" variable is created in the constructor through injection, you need to create a copy of the adalsvc and store it a global variable of the type MsAdalAngular6Service and then execute RenewToken method on this object. Here is a sample code that I have written. I am executign RenewToken in a button click, but in the real scenario, it could be executed in a non-interactical way.

```
        import { Component } from '@angular/core';
        import { MsAdalAngular6Service } from 'microsoft-adal-angular6';

        @Component({
          selector: 'app-root',
          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
        })
        export class AppComponent {
          title = 'app';
          newadalsvc: MsAdalAngular6Service;

          onClickMe() {
           this.getNewToken();
          }

          constructor(private adalSvc: MsAdalAngular6Service) {

             if (!this.adalSvc.userInfo) {
               this.adalSvc.login();
             } else {

              const token = this.adalSvc.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com').subscribe((token: string) => {
               this.newadalsvc = adalSvc;
              alert(token);
              console.log(token);
                 localStorage.setItem('authtoken', token);
                }); 
             }
           }


        getNewToken()
        {
          this.newadalsvc.RenewToken('https://graph.microsoft.com');

//Without calling acquireToken the new token will not be set in the "Local Storage"
this.newadalsvc.acquireToken('https://graph.microsoft.com').subscribe((token) => {
        console.log('Token >>>>>>>>>>>>>>', token);
      });
         }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an http wrapper service/interceptor to intercept all http requests and set the token subscribed by the **this._adalService.acquireToken** method and set in the Authorization header of each http request as follows,

```
      import {Component, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
      import { Headers, Http, Response, RequestOptions, XHRBackend, Request, 
      RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';
      import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
      import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
      import { AdalService } from 'ng4-adal/core';

      export class HttpService extends Http {
         constructor(backend: XHRBackend, options: RequestOptions,private 
         _adalService:AdalService) {
         super(backend, options);
     }

   request(url: string | Request, options: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    return this._adalService
        .acquireToken(this._appDataService.adalConfig.clientId)
        .flatMap<string, Response>((token) => {
            var access_token = token || 
          this._adalService.getCachedToken(this._appDataService.adalConfig.clientId);

            if (typeof (url) == "string") {
                if (!options) {
                    options = {};
                    options.headers = new Headers();
                }
                options.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
                return super.request(url, options);
            }
            else {
                url.headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token);
                return super.request(url, options);
            }
        });
      }
   }
```

The token returned by the **this._adalService.acquireToken** method will be always the current active token. Also set the below configurations for ADAL,

```
        import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

        @Injectable()
      export class AdalConfig {
     constructor() {
     }    

    public get getAdalConfig(): any {
    return {           
        tenant: "tenantName",
        clientId: "clientId",           
        redirectUri: window.location.origin + '/',            
        postLogoutRedirectUri: window.location.origin + '/' + "#/logout",
        extraQueryParameter: "domain_hint=someDomain.com",
        cacheLocation: "localStorage",
        expireOffsetSeconds: "1200"  //Worked for me to avoid token returned as null
      };
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps...